Can I use a shield and staff to cast spells without the Warcaster feat?
I have a character which is a Sorcerer / Cleric multiclass. I took the level in cleric for the purpose of gaining proficiency with both armor and shields.
Am I able to use a staff and shield at the same time to cast my spells without having to take Warcaster?
The Arcane Focus item in the Adventuring Gear section includes a more expensive quarterstaff that can serve as a focus.
Under the rules for Somatic and Material spell components, it says that:

A Somatic component is a forceful gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures. A spellcaster must use at least one of their hands to perform these movements.


A Material component is a particular material used in a spell’s casting, as specified in parentheses in the Components entry. These materials aren’t consumed by the spell unless the spell’s description states otherwise. The spellcaster must have a hand free to access them, but it can be the same hand used to perform Somatic components, if any.
...to use a Spellcasting Focus, you must hold it unless its description says otherwise.

The way I am interpreting the interaction of these features is that they would allow a caster with a shield to satisfy both the material and somatic components of a spell with the hand holding the staff. Thereby allowing the other hand to hold the shield.
Furthermore, this is all permissible without having to gain the Warcaster feat.
Is this accurate?

Related questions in 2014: Can a wizard using an arcane focus quarterstaff and a shield still cast somatic component spells? and
With only one free hand, can I still cast spells with somatic components?

The key is whether you're casting a spell with both Material and Somatic (M+S) components, or just Somatic (S) components. If it's only S, you’ll need a free hand to cast it—unless you have the War Caster feat. This was answered here. Same rules as in 2014, really.

Yes, a staff and shield can be used to cast spells as normal spellcasting foci, without the Warcaster feat.
Divine Casters can use an Holy Symbol as a spellcasting focus.

A Cleric or Paladin can use a Holy Symbol as a Spellcasting Focus.

An Emblem is a type Holy Symbol that can be displayed on a shield.

Emblems must be borne on fabric or a Shield.

Arcane casters, e.g. Sorcerers, Warlocks, and Wizards, can use an Arcane Focus as a spellcasting focus.

An Arcane Focus takes one of the forms in the Arcane Focuses table...

And, a Staff can be an Arcane Focus.

Staff (also a Quarterstaff)

So, yes, a Cleric/Sorcerer Multiclass can simultaneously hold a staff and shield, and use them as spellcasting foci, without the Warcaster feat. However, Warcaster comes with other benefits, as well, like substituting a spell for an opportunity attack, advantage on CON throws to maintain concentration, and an ASI.

Ability Score Increase. Increase your Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma score by 1, to a maximum of 20.


Concentration. You have Advantage on Constitution saving throws that you make to maintain Concentration.


Reactive Spell. When a creature provokes an Opportunity Attack from you by leaving your reach, you can take a Reaction to cast a spell at the creature rather than making an Opportunity Attack.

Plus, there are a few more considerations.
If a spell requires Somatic components, a free hand is necessary for the casting, unless that spell requires both a material and somatic components. In that case, you can perform somatic components with a hand that is holding a material component or focus.1

The spellcaster must have a hand free to access them, but it can be the same hand used to perform Somatic components, if any.

So, if a desired spell only requires somatic and/or verbal components, a character must have a free hand. Fortunately, each character gets a free object Interaction on their turn.

Interacting with Things. You can interact with one object ... for free, during either your move or action.

So, the caster can temporarily drop their Staff (no action), cast the spell (Action/Bonus Action), then pick up their Staff, again (Interaction). This action economy gets pretty tight, though, when the spell is cast as a Reaction (e.g. Shield) on someone else's turn (something Warcaster would allow). In that case, you may be able to drop the Staff, since it requires no action. However, you cannot use the free environment interaction on someone else's turn. So, beware, if you try this, someone may try to swipe your Staff before your next turn.
Finally, it’s worth noting that there is nothing imbalanced about multiclassing in order to gain the same, or similar, benefits granted by feats. Take Skilled, or Skill Expert for example; most of the conferred benefits could be gained by multiclassing in e.g. Rogue or Bard. Multiclassing comes with its own set of opportunity costs, which offset the relative costs and benefits of choosing a given feat.
1: Interestingly, Warcaster does not eliminate the requirements for costly material components, but it does enable a character to cast them with “sword and board”, which multiclassing does not.

@Tarod, Fair. I was just getting to that.

Sure thing. How's that @Tarod?

I was thinking about one part of this answer—the part about dropping with no action. From what I understand, this works differently if we're using the 2024 rules: Is dropping a weapon "free" in terms of action cost? Just in case you agree with my opinion, I thought it might be worth updating your answer.

Mostly
In general, this will work for most arcane casters, but there are a few caveats that are relevant.
First Issue (Spellcasting Focus Restrictions)
The rules for material components states the following (emphasis mine):

If a spell doesn’t consume its materials and doesn’t specify a cost for them, a spellcaster can use a Component Pouch (see chapter 6) instead of providing the materials specified in the spell, or the spellcaster can substitute a Spellcasting Focus if the caster has a feature that allows that substitution.

In other words, you must have a feature that stipulates that an Arcane Focus may be used to cast the spell. Notably, the Spellcasting Feature for Sorcerers, Warlocks, and Wizards are the only ones which state:

Spellcasting Focus. You can use an Arcane Focus as a Spellcasting Focus for your Sorcerer spells.


Spellcasting Focus. You can use an Arcane Focus as a Spellcasting Focus for your Warlock spells.


Spellcasting Focus. You can use an Arcane Focus or your spellbook as a Spellcasting Focus for your Wizard spells.

To summarize, only members of these classes can even use the staff as a focus for their spells.

Second Issue (Class Specific Spellcasting Focus Requirements)
The use of an Arcane Focus can only empower spells from that class' spell list. Therefore, if you are playing as a Wizard/Cleric multiclass, you cannot use this to cast Cleric spells as they are subject to the Cleric spellcasting rules:

Spellcasting Focus. You can use a Holy Symbol as a Spellcasting Focus for your Cleric spells.

So if this multiclass character wishes to cast a Cleric spell, they will need to put away the staff or doff the shield to do so. The exact requirements to do so may be table dependent as the rules for the Utilize Action and Attack Action both stipulate that when using a weapon to attack, you may draw or sheath a weapon for free:

Equipping and Unequipping Weapons. You can either equip or unequip one weapon when you make an attack as part of this action.

Notably, such language is absent when discussing the Magic Action:
https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dnd/free-rules/rules-glossary#MagicAction

When you take the Magic action, you cast a spell that has a casting time of an action or use a feature or magic item that requires a Magic action to be activated.

This DM would allow the caster to simply drop their staff (since I consider it less effort than dropping prone which also has no cost) and draw their holy symbol to cast. However, they would need to wait until their next turn to pick it up. Folks should be aware that other DMs may rule differently. Thank you to Tarod for identifying that dropping an item also consumes a free object interaction.
But frankly, there's a far better way to address the issue for casters of either Cleric or Paladin spells by using the Emblem option for Holy Symbols:

A Cleric or Paladin can use this item as a Spellcasting Focus. Emblems must be borne on fabric or a Shield.

This effectively augments the shield to act as a Holy Symbol and satisfy the Material component for the purpose of casting divine spells and given their hand is holding it, then they can use their shield hand to satisfy the Somatic components as well.
To summarize, only spells from arcane classes which can use the focus may be cast using the staff. Spells from other classes will require changing to the appropriate focus, except for either Cleric or Paladin spells both of which can be cast using the Emblem option for a Holy Symbol.

Third Issue (Costly Components)
I sort of skipped the first half of the the rules for material components earlier, so we'll come back to it now:

If a spell doesn’t consume its materials and doesn’t specify a cost for them, a spellcaster can use a Component Pouch (see chapter 6)
instead of providing the materials specified in the spell, or the
spellcaster can substitute a Spellcasting Focus if the caster has a
feature that allows that substitution.

Any spell which has a cost associated with it cannot be cast with a staff in hand. The staff would need to be dropped in order to pull out the relevant component.
To summarize, if you cast a spell with a costly component, you would still need to drop the staff.

Fourth Issue (No Material Components)
This last issue stems from if a spell requires somatic components and does not require material components. In such a situation the staff must still be dropped using your object interaction in order to satisfy the somatic component requirement that your hand be free.
In order to mitigate this requirement would be to take the Warcaster feat.

Any caster could drop the staff (no action) then use their free object interaction to pick it up.

@nonymous if you're referring to the Second Issue wherein I say they can drop the staff and then cast with their holy symbol, my intent there is that grabbing the holy symbol uses up their free object interaction. Therefore, they can't pick up the staff on their turn.

Ok. Later on you note that they already have shield in hand. So, they wouldn't need to use their free interaction to grab it, right?

From what I understand, dropping weapons works differently under the 2024 rules: Is dropping a weapon "free" in terms of action cost? I'm just sharing this in case it’s helpful for supporting/updating your answer.

@Tarod ooh, that is a subtle change I hadn't picked up on. Thank you!

@nonymous I edited to include the info that Tarod provided. Apparently dropping things is no longer free.

@Pyrotechnical, dubious. There is a leap in logic from a special scenario (Attack action) to the general rule.
